# Getting location ID from user input with pywapi

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode, weather-api

I am trying to make a simple CLI app to retrieve weather data. Unfortunately I haven't got very far with this because I've got stuck at an early stage. This is my code so far:

```
import  pywapi, string

loc=input("What is the city you're closest to?")
loc=loc.lower

#this will give you a dictionary of all cities in the world with this city's name Be specific (city, country)!
loc_id=pywapi.get_location_ids(loc)
#apparently this is a needed workaround to access last item of dictionary
for i in loc_id:
    loc_id=i

#before I go on to code anything further, I just want to use print to check that I've got the two variables I need
print (loc,loc_id)
```

When asked for a city,I could enter London for example or London,UK but both throw up an error: (this is on my local machine)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_weather.py", line 7, in <module>
    loc_id=pywapi.get_location_ids(loc)
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pywapi.py", line 825, in get_location_ids
    loc_id_data = get_loc_id_from_weather_com(search_string)
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pywapi.py", line 856, in get_loc_id_from_weather_com
    url = LOCID_SEARCH_URL % quote(search_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/parse.py", line 694, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/parse.py", line 719, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

And this error, which is different, is when I am using Pythonanywhere

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pydavith/get_weather.py", line 7, in <module>
    loc_id=pywapi.get_location_ids(loc)
  File "/home/pydavith/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pywapi.py", line 825, in get_location_ids
    loc_id_data = get_loc_id_from_weather_com(search_string)
  File "/home/pydavith/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pywapi.py", line 852, in get_loc_id_from_weather_co
m
    search_string = unidecode(search_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/unidecode/__init__.py", line 48, in unidecode_expect_ascii
    bytestring = string.encode('ASCII')
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Does anybody have any idea what is going wrong here? I have duckduckgoed and googled extensively, but nothing has come to light. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: you're using two different versions of python (3.4 and 3.6), so that might explain why the two are different, if not the errors themselves...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have come to a workable answer myself. I am sharing the code here just in case this helps anyone else.

There are so many things I have changed here that it's hard to know where to start. That is to say, there were many errors and needed improvements in the code I originally posted.

```
import  pywapi

# getting input from the user regarding location
#this will give a dictionary of all cities in the world with this city's name
loc=str.title(input("What is the city you're closest to? "))
print("Searching for ", loc)
loc_id=pywapi.get_location_ids(loc)
#Now we have a dictionary (it seems as standard it returns a maximum of ten key:value pairs. Now to convert it to a list just so I can number the entries and ultimately allow the user select the correct entry easily. (Note, there may be a way to do this without converting the dictionary to a list, but I couldn't find it)
loc_list = [ [k,v] for k, v in loc_id.items() ]

#Now I am going to check if the length of the list is over 1 value (i.e. if there's more than one choice, and if there is, to run a for loop printing each entry with a  number 

list_leng=len(loc_list)
if list_leng >1:
#fix some value for x and y to be used in the for loop
    x=1
    y = 0
    for l in loc_id:
        print (x,loc_list[y])
        x = x+1
        y=y+1
    index_choice=(int(input("Which city do you mean? Enter a choice from 1 to " + str(list_leng) + ":  ")))-1
else:
    index_choice=0


loc_id=loc_list[index_choice]
print("You selected ",loc_id[1])
loc_id=loc_id[0]

print ("Location ID for "+loc+" is ",loc_id)

def gettt_weather(loc_id):
     """Fetches the weather information from Weather.com using a location stored under the variable loc_id"""
     print("Looking up the weather for "+loc)
     weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com(loc_id,units='metric')
     print ("Weather.com says that it is "+ weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text'].lower()+" and", weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature']+"°C now in " + loc)

gettt_weather(loc_id)
```

Anyway this works as I wanted it to, so I hope that's useful to some beginner somewhere. If anybody has any further improvements please let me know.